# This is a question for my data structures course, how do I output this matrix?

Tags: matrix, data-structures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZmqn.png)In this assignment you are asked to write a program that reads in two matrixes of size n x m and s x t and then it outputs the resulting multiplication of those two matrixes.   Since sizes of matrices are not known in advance, you need to implement a dynamic memory allocation scheme for matrices. Your program should prompt the user for n, m, s, t, and the elements of each matrix. After that, if the multiplication can be performed on the matrices, your program should output each matrix and the result of the matrix multiplication.

Recall that if the matrix A is of size n x m, and matrix B is of size m x t, the resulting matrix C would be of size n x t.  However, if a matrix is n x m and the other is s x t, these matrices cannot be multiplied if m is not equal to s.

If you are not familiar with the matrix multiplication problem, study the following example in order to find a general solution for the multiplication of two-dimensional matrices. In this example, matrices A and B are of size 3 x 3. An entry Xij indicates an  element X[i][j].

```
         A00    A01   A02                                  B00      B01      B02
  A =             A10    A11   A12      B =         B10      B11      B12
     A20    A21   A22                                  B20      B21      B22
```

Resulting multiplication of the matrices A and B is equal to

```
          A00 * B00 + A01 * B10 + A02 * B20         A00*B01 + A01 * B11 + A02*B21          A00*B02 + A01 *B12 + A02 *B22
```

C    =           A10 * B00 + A11 * B10 + A12 * B20          A10*B01 + A11 * B11 + A12*B21          A10*B02 + A11 *B12 + A12 *B22
A20 * B00 + A21 * B10 + A22 * B20          A20*B01 + A21 * B11 + A22*B21          A20*B02 + A21 *B12 + A22 *B22

To solve the problem, you need to determine how to obtain an entry, say C[i][k], from the entries of matrices A and B. Once you figure this out, the programming will be extremely easy task. Warning; before you start to program, test your solution.

Comment: This is homework.  You should have shown us the code you already wrote along with the results you got.  It is unethical for you to ask us to solve your homework without making at least an attempt to solve it.

Comment: You didn't even tell us what language this needed to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is done by first determining the size of the resultant matrix. You simply take the number of rows of the first matrix, and number of columns of the second matrix. Then you multiply every row of the first matrix with every column of the second matrix. This is the code.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        
        int main()
        {
            int **a, **b, **c;
            int n, m, s, t;
            int i, j;
        
            printf("\nEnter rows for matrix A: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("\nEnter cols for matrix A : ");
            scanf("%d", &m);
            printf("\nEnter rows for matrix B : ");
            scanf("%d", &s);
            printf("\nEnter cols for matrix B: ");
            scanf("%d", &t);
            if(m != s)
            {
                printf("\nCan't multiply two matrices if col of a and row of b are not same.");
                return(0);
            }
        
            a = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
            b = (int **) malloc(s*sizeof(int *));
            c = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
        
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                a[i] = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            for(i=0; i<s; i++)
                b[i] = (int *)malloc(t*sizeof(int));
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                c[i] = (int *)malloc(t*sizeof(int));
        
            printf("\nEnter elements of matrix A :\n");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<m; j++)
                {
                    printf("\tA[%d][%d] = ",i, j);
                    scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
                }
            }
        
            printf("\nEnter elements of matrix B :\n");
            for(i=0; i<s; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<t; j++)
                {
                    printf("\tB[%d][%d] = ",i, j);
                    scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
                }
            }
        
            printf("Elements of matrix A: \n");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<m; j++)
                {
                    printf(" %d ", a[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("Elements of matrix B: \n");
            for(i=0; i<s; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<t; j++)
                {
                    printf(" %d ", b[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                for(j=0; j<s; j++)
                {
                    c[i][j] = 0;
                    for(t=0; t<m; t++)
                        c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][t] * b[t][j];
                }
        
            printf("\n\nResultant matrix :");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("\n\t\t\t");
                for(j=0; j<t; j++)
                    printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
            }
        
        
            return 0;
}
```

So, basically, you do dynamic allocation for rows and columns of each matrix that you need. Then you provide input for them, and calculate the values of matrix C with the following formula:

```
c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][t] * b[t][j];
```

Comment: Why did you assume the answer needed to be in C?

Comment: He didn't specify it, so it could be said that I took my freedom in solving the problem. Anyways, this looks like a typical homework in a C language curriculum. I've been through it at my university. That's the main reason I assumed it needed to be in C. :)